How to test SSE route events on express TS
Hi i tried to test my controller in express ts but I trying testing events sse route but wihtout successul try and that test break the other i don't why
here the road I trying to test client is Response[}
this.router.get('/events', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream; charset=utf-8');
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
        this.clients.push(res);
        const actualGamesList = await this.gameService.getGamesWithData();
        res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(actualGamesList)}\n\n`);
        req.on('close', () => {
            this.clients = this.clients.filter((client) => client !== res);
        });
    });


/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
/* eslint-disable max-lines */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-magic-numbers */
/* /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import { GameController } from './game.controller';
import { GameService } from '@app/services/game.service';
import { Response, Express } from 'express';
import { HTTP_STATUS_CODE, ValidationGameError } from '@app/utils/const';
import { GameInfos, GameMapSize, GameMode } from '@common/game-infos';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as supertest from 'supertest';
import * as http from 'http';
import { Container } from 'typedi';
import { Application } from '@app/app';
import { Game } from '@common/game';
import { ValidationResponse } from '@common/response-infos';
import { DeleteResult } from 'mongodb';
import { Server } from 'http';

describe('GameController', () => {
    let gameServiceMock: sinon.SinonStubbedInstance<GameService>;
    let expressApp: Express;
    let gameController: GameController;
    let server: Server;

    beforeEach(() => {
        gameServiceMock = sinon.createStubInstance(GameService);
        const app = Container.get(Application);
        gameController = new GameController(gameServiceMock as GameService);
        Object.defineProperty(app['gameController'], 'gameService', { value: gameServiceMock });
        expressApp = app.app as Express;
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        sinon.restore();
    });

    describe('sendEventToAllClients', () => {
        it('Should send game data to all clients.', () => {
            const clients = [{ write: sinon.stub() } as unknown as Response, { write: sinon.stub() } as unknown as Response];
            const gameInfos: GameInfos[] = [
                {
                    gid: '1',
                    name: 'Game 1',
                    mode: GameMode.Classic,
                    mapSize: GameMapSize.Medium,
                    description: 'Description',
                    creationDate: new Date(),
                    lastEditDate: new Date(),
                    imageBase64: '',
                    isVisible: true,
                },
            ];
            gameController['sendEventToAllClients'](clients, gameInfos);
            clients.forEach((client) => {
                sinon.assert.calledWith(client.write as sinon.SinonStub, `data: ${JSON.stringify(gameInfos)}\n\n`);
            });
        });
    });

    describe('GameController - GET /events', () => {
        before((done) => {
            server = expressApp.listen(3001, done);
        });
        after((done) => {
            server.close(done);
            sinon.restore();
        });
        // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
        it('Should set the headers, add the client to the client array, send the initial data, and handle the connection closure.', (done) => {
            const actualGamesList: Game[] = [
                {
                    gid: '1',
                    name: 'Game 1',
                    mode: GameMode.Classic,
                    mapSize: GameMapSize.Medium,
                    description: 'Description 1',
                    creationDate: new Date(),
                    lastEditDate: new Date(),
                    imageBase64: '',
                    gameMap: [],
                    isVisible: true,
                },
            ];
            gameServiceMock.getGamesWithData.resolves(actualGamesList);
            const options = {
                hostname: '127.0.0.1',
                port: 3001,
                path: '/api/game/events',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
                    Accept: 'text/event-stream',
                },
            };

            const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
                try {
                    expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                    expect(res.headers['content-type']).to.include('text/event-stream');
                    expect(res.headers['cache-control']).to.equal('no-cache');
                    expect(res.headers['connection']).to.equal('keep-alive');
                    expect(gameController['clients'].length).to.equal(0);

                    let data = '';
                    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                        data += chunk.toString();
                        if (data.includes('\n\n')) {
                            const messages = data.split('\n\n');
                            messages.forEach((message) => {
                                if (message.startsWith('data: ')) {
                                    const jsonData = message.replace('data: ', '');
                                    const parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
                                    expect(parsedData).to.deep.equal(actualGamesList);
                                    req.end();
                                    setTimeout(() => {
                                        expect(gameController['clients'].length).to.equal(0);
                                        done();
                                    }, 50);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    done(error);
                }
            });

            req.on('error', (err) => {
                done(err);
            });

            req.end();
        });

        it('Should handle the error when getGamesWithData rejects.', (done) => {
            // Arrange
            const errorMessage = 'Test error';
            gameServiceMock.getGamesWithData.rejects(new Error(errorMessage));

            const options = {
                hostname: 'localhost',
                port: 3000,
                path: '/api/game/events',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
                    Accept: 'text/event-stream',
                },
            };

            const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
                try {
                    expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(500);

                    let data = '';
                    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                        data += chunk.toString();
                        if (data.includes('\n\n')) {
                            const messages = data.split('\n\n');
                            messages.forEach((message) => {
                                if (message.startsWith('event: error')) {
                                    const jsonData = message.replace('event: error\ndata: ', '');
                                    const parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
                                    expect(parsedData.message).to.equal(errorMessage);

                                    // La connexion doit être fermée par le serveur
                                    expect(res.complete).to.equal(true);

                                    done();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    done(error);
                }
            });

            req.on('error', (err) => {
                done(err);
            });

            req.end();
        });
    });
});

thats the test I have written but its break all and do not work I tried before with supertest and its not function I don t know how to do that correctly all the others route slike post, get is ok but this one is hard
have someone another approach please?
